# : [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider in angularjs can't inject factory into controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-injector

I have an unknown provider error and I'm not sure how to solve it. I think my services, controllers are declared properly. I have tried everything but it doesn't work. my photosFactory factory doesn't work. it's not injected into controller. I'd appreciate any help.

My app.js :

```
 angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
```

my controllers.js :

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
 .controller('PlaylistsCtrl', ['$scope', 'photosFactory', '$http', function ($scope, $http, Util, $ionicLoading, $location, photosFactory) {

        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);

        $scope.allDeals = [];


        $scope.navigate = function(url){
            $location.path(url);
        };
        photosFactory.getPhotos().success(function(data){
            $scope.allDeals= data;

          });
        }])
```

My services.js :

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

         .factory('photosFactory', function($http) {
              return{
                  getPhotos : function() {
                      return $http({
                          url: 'http://www.somecompany.co.uk/bigcapi/feeds/deals/company_id/88',
                          method: 'GET',
                          params: {all: '1', mobileready: 1}
                      })
                  }
              }
          })
```

Comment: Please edit your title it's unclear

Comment: Having this same error, and it is extremely frustrating. Seems to only happen under Ionic.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you don't inject $http in your factory.
Try it

```
.factory('photosFactory', [ '$http', function($http) {
              return{
                  getPhotos : function() {
                      return $http({
                          url: 'http://www.somecompany.co.uk/bigcapi/feeds/deals/company_id/88',
                          method: 'GET',
                          params: {all: '1', mobileready: 1}
                      })
                  }
              };
          }]);
```

There is also a problem when declaring your controller

```
['$scope', 'photosFactory', '$http', function ($scope, $http, Util, $ionicLoading, $location, photosFactory) {
```

The order is very important so you must have something like this

```
['$scope', 'photosFactory', '$http', 'Util', '$ionicLoading', '$location', function ($scope, photosFactory, $http, Util, $ionicLoading, $location,) {
```

Comment: it is still showing the same error, but thank you a response.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

You only declared 3 injectables,

```
controller('PlaylistsCtrl', ['$scope', 'photosFactory', '$http',
```

but want to use 6 - that is not good.

```
function ($scope, $http, Util, $ionicLoading, $location, photosFactory)
```

Mind the order.

Comment: thank you but I'm still getting the same error, I thought it would be something so easy to do, just wanted to move my ajax calls to services but can't seem to do that. they work from controllers but it's bad code and I can't change it so they should be in services but can't get it to work.

Comment: OK, I created small jsfiddle, check http://jsfiddle.net/fdzwqszx/ - it works, of course http call will fail, but the application bootstraps. I removed dependency to ionic.

Comment: ok, thank you, i don't declare my PlaylistsCtrl controller anywhere though.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included your HTML so can't confirm - did you include your services javascript in the index?

Assuming you fix your various import issues, this seems the most likely reason.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should only declare `angular.module('starter.controllers', [])` once. You should use `angular.module('starter.controllers')` instead. (eg. `angular.module('starter.controllers', []).controller ...`